# Discord.js: Trying to create a message system between two different servers with a discord.js bot

Tags: javascript, discord, bots, discord.js

I am trying to get my bot to read messages from a channel in server 1 and send the same message with some added content to a channel in server 2 and vice versa when a message is sent in server 2 in the same channel.

Right now the bot can only read one message and send it perfectly but after that the bot sends the message back to the same channel.

Here is my code below:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  if(message.channel.id = "735085499571765288"){
      var messageContent = message.content;
      client.channels.get('735084968476278805').send(`A Ruse Kid Said: ${messageContent}`);
  }
});

client.on('message', message => {
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  if(message.channel.id === "735084968476278805"){
    var messageContent = message.content;
    client.channels.get('735085499571765288').send(`A High Kid Said: ${messageContent}`)
  }
});
```

Any help or advice appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You have to use at least two `=` for comparison: `if(message.channel.id === "735085499571765288")`

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not spot that :).

Comment: If you use two equals, the if statement is treated as always `true`

Comment: @Erazihel do you mind posting that as an answer so that it can be marked as correct (and you can get your rep)? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using:

```
if (message.channel.id = "735085499571765288") {
```

You are actually assigning `"735085499571765288"` to `message.channel.id`.

If you want to check for equality, you have to use at least two `=`:

```
if (message.channel.id === "735085499571765288") {
```